# Using Worksheet_Change (and/or Worksheet_Calculate) to update source cells

Tags: excel, vba

Row 7 has costs and row 8 has hours (both rows as flat data). Rows 10 and 11 are used to capture how much additional cost and/or additional hours are required. If they enter a value in row 10 then the figure in row 11 must automatically change pro-rata, and if they enter a value in row 11 then the figure in row 10 must also automatically change pro-rata.

I'm calculating the new pro-rata figures in rows 22 and 23. I have tried to use Worksheet_Change to copy the calculated figures back into rows 10 and 11. It works if I'm sending the figures outside of the target area (eg if they're sent into rows 25 and 26), but I get all sorts of errors and/or crashes if I try sending the values directly to rows 10 and 11. I assume that maybe doing this triggers the code again, and an infinite loop is formed? I've also tried using Worksheet_Calculate to pass the values back into rows 10 and 11, in the hope that this will avoid triggering the infinite loop, but to no avail.

Example 1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells1 As Range
Set KeyCells1 = Range("D10:O10")

Dim KeyCells2 As Range
Set KeyCells2 = Range("D11:O11")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells1, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Offset(16, 0).Value = Target.Offset(13, 0)
End If
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells2, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Offset(14, 0).Value = Target.Offset(11, 0)
End If

End Sub
```

Example 2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells1 As Range
    Set KeyCells1 = Range("D10:O10")

    Dim KeyCells2 As Range
    Set KeyCells2 = Range("D11:O11")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells1, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(16, 0).Value = Target.Offset(13, 0)
    End If
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells2, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(14, 0).Value = Target.Offset(11, 0)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells3 As Range
    Set KeyCells3 = Range("D25:O25")

    Dim KeyCells4 As Range
    Set KeyCells4 = Range("D26:O26")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells3, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(-15, 0).Value = Target.Offset(0, 0)
    End If
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells4, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(-15, 0).Value = Target.Offset(0, 0)
    End If

End Sub
```

The code shown here gives the error "Compile error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name". If I combine into a single Worksheet_Change and send the formulae outputs directly into rows 3 and 4 then instead I get "Runtime error 28: Out Of Stack Space".

Comment: The [Worksheet Calculate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)) event doesn't have a `Target` argument. If you are using the Change event, you need to toggle `Application.EnableEvents` to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: That seems to have worked! Thank you so much.